# What can you say about the order of this group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group of order $2n$.

Let H and K be 2 normal subgroups of $G$. If $H\cap K=$ {$e$}, what can you say about $n$?

I can't think of a restriction about $n$!!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

We can say $2n$ is an even multiple of $|H||K|$.

Can it be any even multiple? Yes, it can.

We can let $G$ be the product $H\times K \times \mathbb Zw$ to make $|G|=|H||K|w$